# How to code for Raspberry on ordinary PC

Tags: software-development

I am learning how to make things with Raspberry.
For now I do coding right on the Raspberry. However, this is a very slow computer and I believe there is much more efficient way of working.

How to code for Raspberry on ordinary PC which is much more powerful?
I’d like to use professional tool like Pycharm on my PC, do all the job on PC and simply deploy the code onto raspberry.
What options are available?

Comment: Most people who write Pi software probably work remotely. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-development-on-raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-ping ("Tutorial: Remote Development on Raspberry Pi")

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to mount my raspberrypi to a local directory using `sshfs` and then open that directory in my editor. When I want to run the program on the pi, I use a terminal (which could be the terminal built into the editor), ssh into the pi, and run the program from there.

After [installing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) `sshfs`, which is done differently depending on your operating system, it is fairly simple to use:

`sshfs user@hostname:/path/to/code/on/pi /local/path/to/code`

Answer (score 2):

I use vscode remotely, works really well!

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioCodeRemoteDevelopmentOverSSHToARaspberryPiIsButter.aspx